# How to change the headers url while using request.post?

Tags: python, python-requests

I was a bit confused on changing an standard `http post` header:

`POST / HTTP/1.1`

into:

`POST /xxx HTTP/1.1`

I am using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) lib for python.
Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: from `/` to `/xxx` you're changing the url not the headers

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem? what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

This will set a `GET / HTTP/1.1` protocol header

```
r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

This will set a `GET /user HTTP/1.1` protocol header

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why only /user come to the url rather than the whole thing, thank you sooooo much.